# hibernate entity discovery only works inside the same folder

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Spring Boot project with Hibernate.

- The project does **not** have a hibernate.cfg.xml file.
- The project also does **not** have an applicationContext.xml file.

Nevertheless, all works well.

However, when I start adding new hibernate entities, then things go wrong. For some reason, the system only finds them when I put them inside the package of the other hibernate entities.

So, this leads me to believe that I do need additional configuration to help the auto-discovery mechanism. But what is the state-of-art in 2020 ? (I assume that the above xml files are now deprecated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally overlooked these annotations which were present on the SpringBootApplication class.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.domain.foo.bar.*"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages ={"com.domain.foo.bar.*"})
@EntityScan(basePackages ={"com.domain.foo.bar.*"})
public class SpringBootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
}
```

I needed to add my packages here.

Answer (score 1):

If you use spring + hibernate then it solved by @ComponenScan annotation.

If pure hibernate then I think you need persistence.xml

> EntityManager is the class that performs database interactions in JPA.
>   It is initialized through a configuration file named persistence.xml.
>   This file is found in the META-INF folder in your CLASSPATH, which is
>   typically packaged in your JAR or WAR file. The persistence.xml file
>   contains:
>
> - The named "persistence unit," which specifies the persistence framework you're using, such as Hibernate or EclipseLink.
> - A collection of properties specifying how to connect to your database,    as well as any customizations in the persistence
>     framework
> - A list of entity classes in your project

Comment: Will try this first thing in the morning.

Comment: It turns out that in Spring Boot there are some more specific annotations now, which I've added in an anwer below.

Comment: Next time, please specify what you are using except hibernate:)

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebsocketApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebsocketApplication.class, args);
    }

}



this code is enough to work everything well if you are using spring boot.You just need that all your packages were on one level lower than this class